# Create new image based on standard one

Tags: docker

I have installed Docker and have running some Ubuntu image with command:

```
sudo docker run ubuntu
```

I would like to create some text file on it and find it next time the same image will run. How to achieve that?

UPD.

Got problems with attaching to docker. 
I have running docker

```
docker ps -a
aef01293fdc9        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         6 hours ago         Up 6 hours                                      priceless_ramanujan
```

Since it is `Up` mode, I suppose I don't need to execute command:

```
docker start priceless_ramanujan
```

So, I run command `attach`

```
docker attach priceless_ramanujan
```

And got nothing in output while command not returns.

Why I can't get to container's bash?

Comment: I tried to add a few details about `images` and `containers`, `run`, `start` and their differences. When starting with docker I was also confused with `run`, kept spinning up new containers and couldn't understand why I was "losing" my changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example:

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu
root@4d5643e8c1a8:/# echo "test" > test.txt
root@4d5643e8c1a8:/# cat test.txt 
test
root@4d5643e8c1a8:/# exit
exit

$ docker run -it ubuntu
root@cdb44750bffc:/# cat test.txt
cat: test.txt: No such file or directory
root@cdb44750bffc:/#
```

### docker run `image_name`

This command creates and starts a **new** container based on the provided `image_name`. If a name is not set for the container, a random one is generated and assigned by docker. In the above example 2 containers were created based on `ubuntu`.

- with `docker ps -a` we can see that `modest_jennings` and `optimistic_leakey` are the random names created:

  ```
  $ docker ps -a
  CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                     PORTS                  NAMES
  cdb44750bffc        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"              About a minute ago   Exited (1) 4 seconds ago                          optimistic_leakey
  4d5643e8c1a8        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"              2 minutes ago        Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                          modest_jennings
  ```
- `cat test.txt` failed the 2nd time because the file didn't exist. The container started from a "clean" `ubuntu` image.

Actually, we created `test.txt` inside `modest_jennings` only.

### docker start `container_name`

This command  starts a stopped container. So, in our case, the file is still there:

```
$ docker start modest_jennings 
modest_jennings
$ docker attach modest_jennings 
root@4d5643e8c1a8:/# cat test.txt
test
root@4d5643e8c1a8:/#
```

### docker commit `container_name` `image_name`

This command is to create a new image, so that you can use it later and run containers based on that image. Continuing our example...

```
$ docker commit modest_jennings my_ubuntu
sha256:a4357f37153ac0b94e37315595f1a3b540538283adc3721df4d4e3b39bf8334f
$ docker run -it my_ubuntu
root@2e38616d532a:/# cat test.txt 
test
root@2e38616d532a:/#
```

Comment: Since my container is `Up` I decided t ommit `docker start modest_jennings` but failed with `attach`. Why? More details in question body UPD.

Comment: I believe this is happening because you didn't use `-it` at `docker run ...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom image, you can create a Dockerfile

```
`FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ADD ./test.txt /tmp/`
```

after you can build it `docker build -t ubuntu:custom .`
and finally run your custom image `docker run --name myubuntu ubuntu:custom sleep 3000`

You can check your file with `docker exec -it myubuntu /bin/bash` and `more /tmp/test.txt`